# hosting on godaddy, GoogleApps and MSAzure

Tags: g-suite, godaddy, azure

We are looking to host for a startup with the following configuration
a) domain using GoDaddy as registrar
b) use google apps- mail, calendar, docs- email attraction also because we can integrate Gmail using IMAP to Outlook and work offline
c) host on gogrid/ MS Azure- getting benefits for being a start-up

Does the approach see right- would this be a challenge- anything to look out for?

Comment: that sounds more like a http://www.superuser.com question but to answer it, you can do it using Godaddy's Total DNS Control, with that you can setup your gmail app to your domain and also any hosting company you may want to host your domain for you. GoDaddy also offers you a tool to automatic setup your domain to use gmail app at https://www.godaddy.com/gdshop/google/gmail_login.asp

Answer (score 0):

This setup should be ok: GoDaddy should let you create the various DNS records you need (MX, CNAMEs for Google Apps, etc.).

One thing you'll want to verify is that Go Grid/Microsoft Azure will allow you to host your DNS elsewhere (GoDaddy) and give you static IPs for your hosted application(s) so that you can create reliable DNS records that aren't going to change.

If that's not an option, you may have to host your DNS records with Go Grid/Microsoft Azure, but you'll then need to make sure they allow you to create your own A, MX, CNAME records for Google Apps (and verify that you can create records for domains that you don't control; I've had "Advanced DNS" packages from hosting companies before that only permitted you to create records for yourdomain.com, so Google Apps was not going to work).